# What's the fastest way to find the factors of a number in c++?

Tags: c++, factors

I have been struggling for speed and haven't found anything useful online. I'm also using boost::multiprecision 1024 bit integers. What's the fastest possible way to find all of the multiples for such large numbers?

I have tried:

- looping from 1 to square root of the number
- incrementing by 2 if the number is odd
- keeping everything I can out of the loop
- compiling in release mode (vs2019)

Here's my code so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::multiprecision;

void multiples()
{
    __int64 startthing, endthing;
    __int64 freq = _Query_perf_frequency();

    int1024_t divisor = 0, thing = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        //displayer.join();
        cout << "\nEnter a number\n";
        cin >> thing;

        if (thing == 0 && !cin.fail())
            break;
        cout << endl;

        while (cin.fail())
        {
            cout << "I said integer you rule breaker\n";

            // get rid of failure state
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cin >> thing;
        }

        int1024_t limit = sqrt(thing);
        int1024_t step = (thing & 1 ? 2 : 1); // odd number = odd factors
        startthing = _Query_perf_counter();   // start timer

        for (int1024_t i = 1; i <= limit; i += step) 
        {
            if ((thing % i) == 0)
            {
                divisor = thing / i;
                cout << i << ", " << divisor << "\n";
            }
        }
        endthing = _Query_perf_counter();

        cout << "\nThat took " << (endthing - startthing) / (double)freq << " seconds.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: For a value `n`, try finding prime values between `2` and the (integer) square root of `n`, inclusive.   Then loop over the prime values, and count how many times each one divides exactly into `n`.   From that, you'll be able to work out all prime factors (obviously) and, if needed, derive all the composite factors.   For small values, this approach might be slower than a brute-force loop (that, say, checks if every possible value in a range is a factor).  But, for larger values of `n` there will come a point where this approach is faster than the brute-force loop.

Comment: [Nobody knows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization).

Comment: "All the multiples of such a large number" there are infinitely many multiples, since there are infinitely many natural numbers. You're still looking for divisors of the number, right?

Comment: @fabian Evenly divisible multiples, or factors.

Comment: @Peter code should be copyable now.

Comment: @PupperGump What is the max number to factor?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The max of int1024_t. The signed number is over 300 digits long.

Comment: For prime values near the max of int1024_t, you are essentially asking to prove that it is a prime.  Proving a 1000-bit number number is a prime it quite challenging.  I suggest you start with, say 128-bit or 64 bit integers.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I know, but to avoid more typing I'm just using 1024 bit numbers and entering in numbers only in the quintillions to test. I'll try even larger numbers when I can get it to find the factors of LLONG_MAX in less than a second.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **C Quadratic Sieve**, it's not using GMP or another library... it will provide you the prime factors of N (when N <=  220-bit) : https://github.com/michel-leonard/C-Quadratic-Sieve. Output is done with strings since numbers are larger than 64-bit. This is the fastest way ?!

Answer (score 0):

The best approach here is probably to calculate the prime factorization of the number and then printing out the products of all possible combinations of those prime factors.

Here's a implementation without much optimization using uint64_t instead of multiprecision that completes within 305 ms for input  10,000,000,000,000,000 on my machine.

Note that the preformance will get significantly worse for a larger number of distinct prime factors. (12132 ms for the product of the smallest 14 primes). This is caused by the fact that there are just more combinations to calculate/print.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using PrimeFactors = std::vector<std::pair<uint64_t, uint64_t>>;

std::vector<std::pair<uint64_t, uint64_t>> FindFactors(uint64_t n)
{
    PrimeFactors primeFactors;

    uint64_t square = static_cast<uint64_t>(std::sqrt(n));
    for (uint64_t i = 2; i <= square && i <= n; ++i)
    {
        bool isPrime = true;
        for (auto [prime, exponent] : primeFactors)
        {
            if (prime * prime > i)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (i % prime == 0u)
            {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isPrime)
        {
            uint64_t count = 0;
            while (n % i == 0)
            {
                ++count;
                n /= i;
            }
            primeFactors.emplace_back(i, count);
            if (count != 0)
            {
                square = static_cast<uint64_t>(std::sqrt(n));
            }
        }
    }
    if (n != 1)
    {
        primeFactors.emplace_back(n, 1);
    }
    return primeFactors;
}

void PrintFactors(uint64_t factor, PrimeFactors::const_iterator pos, PrimeFactors::const_iterator const end)
{
    while (pos != end)
    {
        while (pos != end && pos->second == 0)
        {
            ++pos;
        }
        auto newFactor = factor;
        for (auto count = pos->second; count != 0; --count)
        {
            newFactor *= pos->first;
            std::cout << newFactor << '\n';
            PrintFactors(newFactor, pos + 1, end);
        }
        ++pos;
    }
}

int main()
{
    using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;

    uint64_t const input = 10'000'000'000'000'000ull;
    //uint64_t const input = 2ull * 3ull * 5ull * 7ull *11ull * 13ull *17ull * 19ull * 23ull * 29ull *31ull*37ull * 41ull*43ull;

    auto start = Clock::now();
    auto factors = FindFactors(input);

    // print
    std::cout << 1 << '\n';
    PrintFactors(1, factors.begin(), factors.end());
    auto end = Clock::now();
    std::cout << "took " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() << " ms\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Potential bug**

`int1024_t limit = sqrt(thing);` risks imprecision with as it employs FP math with less precision  than `int1024_t`.

A good compiler calculates nearby `a % b` and `a / b` for about the same time cost `a % b` alone.

So instead of `i <= limit`.

```
    // for (int1024_t i = 1; i <= limit; i += step) 
    for (int1024_t i = 1; i <= thing/i; i += step) 
    {
        if ((thing % i) == 0)
    ...
```

**Factor**

A more complex approach, but speeds things up is to reduce `thing` by each factor found.  With 72, form the set 1,2,2,2,3,3 to report the factors.  This quickly avoids many iterations for composite numbers - does nothing for primes.

Better to have a list of primes - either initial fixed - or calculated as you go, to discern the next division candidate.

Comment: My goal was to avoid any extra math in the loop, but are you saying that it will use the result from `thing / i` in `thing % i` ?

Comment: @PupperGump Yes.  Profiling code for performance is better than assuming _extra math_ costs.  Could also look to `div()`.  Notice the `limit` calculation is not needed here.  But in any case, more important to get it functionally correct than fast and selectively buggy.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest to implement what I can suggest to you is [Pollard's Rho Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm), it is most simple algorithm that can be implemented with moderate speed in mind.

I implemented it from scratch for you just now in my code below. I didn't improve your code but instead decided to implement my own solution to suggest to you.

Besides this algorithm I also used several other supplementary algorithms - [Fermat Primality Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test), [Trial Division Factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division), [Modular Exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method), [Euclidean Algorithm for Greatest Common Divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

As you noticed I mentioned Trial Division Factorization Algorithm, you implemented a kind of this algorithm, but without optimizations.

My Pollard Rho code can be speeded up 5x-7x times more by using some optimization tweaks, for example instead of computing GCD on every step we can accumulate `m = (m * (n + x - y)) % m` and then compute GCD onces in e.g. 32-64 iterations.

Throughout last years I also implemented many other very fast methods like [Quadratic Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve), [Lenstra Elliptic Curve Factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization), [Dixon Factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_factorization_method), [Rational Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_sieve). Two first algorithms are especially fast.

I also dream of implementing [General Number Field Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) and/or [Special Number Field Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_number_field_sieve). It is fastest knwon algorithm ever implemented. If anyone reading this post has suggestions about where to get nice detailed description of these two algorithms, please say.

In main() function you may see call to `Test<u128>(128, 1 << 4);`, it says to use `uint128_t` from [Boost.Multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) and generate all 128 random bits, also do 16 = 1 << 4 tests (numbers). You change it to `Test<u256>(160, 4);` if you want to use `uint256_t`, fill only lower 160 bits with random and do only 4 tests (numbers).

For testing purposes I generated 16 random numbers of 128 bits each and factored them. Also measured time of each factorization, timings results provided below. You may notice that some numbers I marked as `(composite)`, this means they are not fully factored within my limit of time 5 seconds.

```
bits 128 n   17915842262360463674173950549775867426 (time  0.301 sec): 2, 21491, 625491661, 6663909434473426813831063,
bits 128 n  121789037182623039222703653461854881250 (time  7.919 sec): 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 773, 25208597605717576035747198646697 (composite),
bits 128 n  307371884173919060462821521512767593179 (time  0.420 sec): 241, 220189, 514934711, 11248621656771703048561,
bits 128 n  266395470738394920077404067884772049106 (time  1.608 sec): 2, 79, 3814777, 11113185637, 39770589213438245843,
bits 128 n  218410814367399081134457596486417399306 (time  0.515 sec): 2, 2253037, 647687357, 74835971169902276823917,
bits 128 n   16482569851851212099502767012175086110 (time  0.027 sec): 2, 5, 11, 2141, 3049, 3043939, 75068843889167669636551,
bits 128 n  160703579509731455803735341216177353103 (time  0.271 sec): 3, 7, 11, 31, 431, 565517, 1885909, 692729483, 70476533867,
bits 128 n  192159263553652243400146755624390868731 (time  0.007 sec): 3, 3, 21351029283739138155571861736043429859,
bits 128 n    8229443485039163439576458639833811949 (time  8.984 sec): 3, 27343147828346387813192152879944603983 (composite),
bits 128 n  124832979048157150649143271603651047466 (time  8.487 sec): 2, 11, 1973, 2875938327608099125677170704595011 (composite),
bits 128 n    6615854566474342988962229492221749308 (time  0.015 sec): 2, 2, 7, 7, 7, 89317, 538716169090875806007062712917,
bits 128 n   25426430801796098780452692480331939195 (time  1.058 sec): 5, 4153, 1001142943, 122308770445399800153641,
bits 128 n    5955299750622414108265807831349122319 (time  0.022 sec): 31, 1780459, 1078971453813117691743928660211,
bits 128 n  301907051652587930114332388103639684834 (time  2.934 sec): 2, 3, 449653, 6496151, 207223343423, 83128457787031,
bits 128 n   80608598476156315717349807734786183513 (time  8.660 sec): 80608598476156315717349807734786183513 (composite),
bits 128 n   46394604909384515366847525985397252507 (time  8.773 sec): 46394604909384515366847525985397252507 (composite),
```

From timings above you may notice that if a number has 2nd largest prime factor of 32 bits then it spends around 1 second to find it. Largest prime factor may be of any size, even 1024 bits, it doesn't matter. For algorithm only matters 2nd largest factor size, and if it is below 32 bits then only 1 second is needed to fully factor whole number using Pollard Rho.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/5WM1ob6os)

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

#define ASSERT_MSG(cond, msg) { if (!(cond)) throw std::runtime_error("Assertion (" #cond ") failed at line " + std::to_string(__LINE__) + "! Msg '" + std::string(msg) + "'."); }
#define ASSERT(cond) ASSERT_MSG(cond, "")

using u32  = uint32_t;
using u64  = uint64_t;
using u128 = boost::multiprecision::uint128_t;
using u256 = boost::multiprecision::uint256_t;
using u512 = boost::multiprecision::uint512_t;

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> Factor_TrialDiv(T n) {
    std::vector<T> fs;
    while (u32(n & 1) == 0) {
        fs.push_back(2);
        n >>= 1;
    }
    for (T d = 3; d * d <= n; d += 2)
        while (n % d == 0) {
            n /= d;
            fs.push_back(d);
        }
    if (n != 1)
        fs.push_back(n);
    return fs;
}

template <typename T> struct DWordOf;
template <> struct DWordOf<u32> { using type = u64; };
template <> struct DWordOf<u64> { using type = u128; };
template <> struct DWordOf<u128> { using type = u256; };
template <> struct DWordOf<u256> { using type = u512; };

template <typename T>
T PowMod(T const & a, T b, T const & c) {
    using DT = typename DWordOf<T>::type;
    T d = a, r = 1;
    while (b != 0) {
        if (b & 1)
            r = T((DT(r) * d) % c);
        d = T((DT(d) * d) % c);
        b >>= 1;
    }
    return r;
}

template <typename T>
bool Fermat_IsProbablePrime(T const & n, size_t ntrials = 32) {
    if (n <= 16)
        return n == 2 || n == 3 || n == 5 || n == 7 || n == 11 || n == 13;
    thread_local std::mt19937_64 rng{std::random_device{}()};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ntrials; ++i)
        if (PowMod<T>(rng() % (n - 3) + 2, n - 1, n) != 1)
            return false;
    return true;
}

template <typename T>
T GCD(T a, T b) {
    while (b != 0)
        std::tie(a, b) = std::make_tuple(b, a % b);
    return a;
}

template <typename T, typename F>
std::vector<T> Factor_PollardRho(T const & n, size_t ntrials, F && finish) {
    using DT = typename DWordOf<T>::type;
    thread_local std::mt19937_64 rng{std::random_device{}()};
    if (n < (1 << 16))
        return Factor_TrialDiv<T>(n);
    if (Fermat_IsProbablePrime<T>(n))
        return {n};
    auto f = [&](T x){ return T((DT(x) * x + 1) % n); };
    for (size_t itry = 0; itry < ntrials; ++itry) {
        T x = rng() % (n - 2) + 1;
        for (size_t icycle = 1;; icycle <<= 1) {
            if (finish())
                return {n};
            bool failed = false;
            T y = x;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < icycle; ++i) {
                x = f(x);
                auto const g = GCD(n, n + x - y);
                if (g == 1)
                    continue;
                ASSERT(n % g == 0);
                if (g == n) {
                    failed = true;
                    break;
                }
                auto fs0 = Factor_PollardRho(n / g, ntrials, finish),
                     fs1 = Factor_PollardRho(g, ntrials, finish);
                fs0.insert(fs0.end(), fs1.begin(), fs1.end());
                return fs0;
            }
            if (failed)
                break;
        }
    }
    ASSERT(false);
}

template <typename T, typename F>
std::vector<T> Factor(T const & n, F && finish) {
    auto fs = Factor_PollardRho(n, 8, finish);
    std::sort(fs.begin(), fs.end());
    return fs;
}

inline double Time() {
    static auto const gtb = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - gtb).count();
}

template <typename T>
T Rand(size_t bits = sizeof(T) * 8) {
    thread_local std::mt19937_64 rng{std::random_device{}()};
    T r = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < bits; i += 64) {
        size_t const cbits = std::min<size_t>(64, bits - i);
        r <<= cbits;
        r |= rng() >> (64 - cbits);
    }
    return r;
}

template <typename T>
std::string IntToStr(T n) {
    std::string r;
    while (n != 0) {
        u64 constexpr mod = 1'000'000'000'000'000'000ULL;
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << u64(n % mod);
        r = ss.str() + r;
        n /= mod;
    }
    return r;
}

template <typename T>
void Test(size_t bits, size_t ntests) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ntests; ++i) {
        auto n = Rand<T>(bits);
        auto tim = Time();
        auto fs = Factor<T>(n, [&]{ return Time() - tim >= 5; });
        tim = Time() - tim;
        std::cout << "bits " << bits << " n " << std::setw(40) << IntToStr(n) << " (time "
            << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << std::setw(6) << tim << " sec): ";
        for (auto const & f: fs)
            std::cout << IntToStr(f) << (Fermat_IsProbablePrime<T>(f) ? "" : " (composite)") << ", ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    try {
        Test<u128>(128, 1 << 4);
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception const & ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```